# problem accent français on texstudio

Tags: texstudio, accents, texshop

I am using these packages to write my document in french. I am using texstudio on mac os x. The problem is about accent. e.g , for the word vidéo, I have to write vid\'eo which is very complicated if we write 200 pages. When I write vidéo directly, I get **vidÃl’o**. I tried a lot of proposed [solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125017/texstudio-ignores-some-accent-keyboard-input) but it does not work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}  %support francais et anglais
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% Pour utiliser des fichiers UTF-8
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{thumbpdf}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{lscape}  %for the landscape table
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure your document using the encoding you pass to it with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. You could encode it in UTF-8 and use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: @moewe, I did not use utf8. When I uncomment UTF8 i  have a compiling problem

Comment: when I write and accent and I used the UTF encoding and package, I get this error for exemple for the word "système" **Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �me (U+DA)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. Les syst�me** I compile with pdflatex

Comment: Can you verify that your file really uses UTF-8? That is check with a different editor? Sometimes editors have trouble re-coding files that are open.

Comment: @moewe, I edit my question

Comment: OK, so TeXstudio claims you file is UTF-8. But can you verify that independently, i.e. with a different editor? Can you give a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: You're screenshot just shows, that the default encoding of your TXS is utf8, this does not say anything about an individual document you are using.

Comment: Comment aside: package `times` is totally deprecated. Loading `mathptmx` is enough.

Comment: @moewe, I get the same problem with TexShop

Comment: If you get  vidÃl’o when you do not specify `inputenc` then your file _is_ in `UTF-8` encoding and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` shoudl allow you to type the accented letters directly. If it doesn't work please fix your example to be a complete document including the word  vidéo  and show the output, and log file that you get.