# I can't type anything with FreeMonoTengwar font

Tags: fonts, xetex, texstudio, font-encodings, keyboard

I've successfully installed the [FreeMonoTengwar font](http://freetengwar.sourceforge.net/freemonotengwar.html) and the [keyboard layout](http://freetengwar.sourceforge.net/keylayouts.html), and it works perfectly on simple programs such as Notepad:

[image]

but for some reason when I follow the steps given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169156/121450) Texstudio does not write anything. I checked everything: I always use UTF-8, I changed the font to Free Mono Tengwar, my preamble is the same as the one cited, but when I try to write with the new layout no character appears in the .tex. When I copy-and-paste, though, characters are correctly pasted and the whole thing compiles fine:

[image]
[image]

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\telcontar}[Renderer=Graphite]{Tengwar Telcontar}

\begin{document}

    {\telcontar }

\end{document}
```

What can be happening? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added the MWE. I don't thing I can add more, since my problem is literally that I can't input tengwar characters XD

Comment: ah sorry it's late here I misunderstood. You already have the font installed correctly for xetex it's a matter of making it show in the editor. Of course you can always cut and paste from notepad if nothing else works, sorry I can't help with texstudio I don't have it. I will revert the edit I made to your code block. there are plenty of texstudio users on this site, someone may answer later

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your editor, not XeLaTeX (or LuaLaTeX, which should also work with `Renderer=`).

You might be able to select your Elvish monospace font as your editor font in the menu.  The default almost certainly does not support Elvish, which is why you don’t see it.

An alternative would be to define ASCII macros for Elvish, such as:

```
\newcommand\tinco{{\telcontar\char"E000}}
\newcommand\parma{{\telcontar\char"E001}}
```

and so on.  You would then need to spell out any Elvish words as `\tinco\yanta\parma` and the like. The vowels and other diacritics, as Unicode combining characters, would need to be written after the base characters, due to technical limitations.

It would also be possible to write a mapping function that transforms a Latin transliteration into this font’s mapping of Elvish script.  This might use expl3 regex substitutions, Lua hooks, or a SIL font mapping.

Comment: I would assume that the problem is not that the font the editor uses doesn’t provide the characters, but somehow the input is just not supported. Notice that the OP was able to paste elvish characters into the editor from elsewhere and they were actually shown in the editor.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I suggested the macros so that, even if the input method didn’t work, the OP could still type them and proofread in any editor. A font mapping would also work.

Answer (score 0):

When using `xelatex` there is no need for `usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\telcontar}[Renderer=Graphite]{Tengwar Telcontar} 

\begin{document}

    {\telcontar      ⁘ }

\end{document}
```

[image: Tengar]

Try to change the encoding correctly to unicode. See the image below:
[image: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125033/175371]

Comment: The problem persists if I delete that line: I cannot write any character in Texstudio using the new keyboard layout.

Comment: In my question I mentioned that I've always used UTF-8. That includes the Editor -> Default Font Encoding you show.